# VSCode keyboard issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

for some reason, when writing JavaScript files in VSCode, everytime I press on the forward slash key ("/"), a semi-colon shows up instead (no forward slashes appears). This only happens on JavaScript files. 
To anyone using VSCode, have you ever encountered an issue like this?
I'm kinda new to VSCode so maybe that's why.
But, I just can't seem to find any answers to this issue anywhere, which is why I am asking it here.

BTW, I have a standard qwerty keyboard and my computer is a DELL XPS 15 9570 running on Windows 10 using the standard English US keyboard on Windows 10. Intel Core i7 9th gen with Nvidia 1650 if this ever get's useful.

Comment: What do you get when you press SHIFT+/ ?

Comment: when I do SHIFT+/, I get ?. It's only when I just do "/", that this issue occurs for some reason.

Comment: Any extensions installed? Can you try deactivating the extensions and try to see if they affect the shortcut?

Comment: I'm curious... I'm not entirely sure if you can do this, but maybe your VS Code is reading your keyboard as UK English rather than US English? I know keyboard layouts can have minor differences. Maybe if you have a dig around, there's a setting somewhere in preferences. I use a Mac so I wouldn't know where it'd be on Windows, sorry about that. Cam.

Answer (score 0):

If you have these two extensions installed, disable them.

1. Path autocomplete
2. Smart semicolon code

I had the same issue and got fixed when I disabled these two extensions.